# How do remote web services handles reference type parameters

Tags: c#, web-services, pass-by-reference

Consider the scenario,

I have a web service hosted on Machine-A. It has a web method accepting reference type parameter. This web service is consumed by another application running in Machine-B.

In this case, as per my knowledge, Machine-B will pass reference to the memory block allocated for the reference type to web service (which is residing in Machine-A). Then, how Machine-A can resolve that memory address? Or, what is the mechanism which handles all this and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Machine-B dosn't pass a refernce to the object to Machine-A. The webservice handles this through serializsation.
The Object is serialized on Machine-B, sent to Machine-A and gets deserialized. So Machine-A has a copy of the Object from Mashine-B.

You can read more abeout serialisation at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Vstudio/ms233843.aspx